# Reputation gained from answer based on score of the question

Tags: feature-request

An idea,

The reputation you gain from an accepted answer should be dependant on the score of the question you're answering.

Questions with a higher score give answerers a bigger bonus upon an accepted answer.

Good idea?

Comment: recommended reading: **[The Trouble With Popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/)** "Popularity is a tough thing. I’m tempted to call it a curse..."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm afraid I have to disagree with your idea.
It will encourage people to answer the highest upvoted questions, but these are not always the best questions.
It will encourage the phenomenon of "bikeshedding" - a question about the color of the bike shed will get a lot of discussion and upvotes, because it's an easy subject. While a question about the nuclear power plant will get a few votes and little answers/discussion, because it requires very specific knowledge.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Ohh well, shame about the down votes, shouldn't they be for if the question is unsuitable, not just because people don't like the question?

Comment: @ToddDavies: It's marked as a feature-request and voting on meta's a little different: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq/#vote-differences

Comment: So, if it's a feature request, you upvote/downvote depending on if you like the feature?

Comment: @ToddDavies Yes, exactly!